# Exec command giving error "No such file or directory" when I try to execute the below code on cmd in golang with exec. Can someone help me with this?

Tags: macos, go, goland

"No such file or directory" when I try to execute the below code on cmd in golang with exec.
This is basically because of the white spaces in this path ->

```
/Users/ltuser/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome Beta/Default
```

How do i escape the white spaces when executing with exec command in golang cmd in macos?

```
        cmdStr := fmt.Sprintf("find /Users/ltuser/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome Beta/Default -mindepth 1 ! -name Preferences -delete")
        args := strings.Fields(cmdStr)
        cmd := exec.Command(args[0], args[1:]...)
        op, err := cmd.CombinedOutput()
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println("error",err.Error())
        }
```

Comment: Instead of sprintf and parse, fil out the args with the strings

Comment: @BurakSerdar can you help me with this or an example? didn't actually understood you. Thanks.

Comment: @Riteshkumar my answer is saying same thing

Answer (score 1):

> How do i escape the white spaces when executing with exec command in golang cmd in macos?

```
"find /Users/ltuser/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome Beta/Default -mindepth 1 ! -name Preferences -delete"
```

It's important to distinguish between `exec.Command` and a shell statement.   When you're running things at "the command line", you're running them in a shell.  This lets you create pipelines with `|`, redirect with `<`, `>`, etc, use variables, and so on.  It has a specific syntax for executing executables in the `$PATH` such as `find`.  In shell syntax, a sequence of characters `executable arg1 arg2 arg3` will be parsed around the spaces.  `executable`, if a program found in the path, will be executed with [`exec`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/exec.3.html). The arguments, split by spaces, will become the arguments to `exec`.

That's why when you run a command like your `find` at the shell, strings like   `/Users/ltuser/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome Beta/Default` must be enquoted if they're to be passed as one argument.

But you're not running this at the shell, even though you expressed your command as a sequence of string-separated values.  That's why you

```
        args := strings.Fields(cmdStr)
```

That's where your path with spaces becomes multiple arguments.

`exec.Command` has an interface like the OS `exec`, because that's what it uses to execute your commands for you.  And that's why it takes a *list* of strings; no parsing need be done, and no characters in the strings need to be escaped.

So just split up the arguments in the code, and pass them straight into
`exec.Command`:

```
cmd := exec.Command("find", 
   "/Users/ltuser/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome Beta/Default", 
   "-mindepth",
    ... ... ...,
)
```

Comment: what is `Copy`?  your example should work fine.  Strings can have spaces.  They only cause problems if something is breaking around spaces